# How to find correlation of $X$ and $Y$ given the joint pdf?

Tags: self-study, correlation

The $X$ and $Y$ have joint pdf s.t. $f(x,y) = e^{-y}$ for $0 \leq x \leq y$.

I need to find the $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$, so I got marginal $f_{X}(x) = e^{-x}$ and $f_{Y}(y) = ye^{-y}$ and$\text{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}(XY)- \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y) = 3-[1-e^{y}(y+1)] \cdot [e^{x}(x^2+2x+2)]$.

I have no idea about how to get correlation of $X$ and $Y$. I trying use $\text{Cov}(X,Y)/\sqrt{(\text{Var}(X)\text{Var}(Y))}$. While it's a huge number to calculate, could any one have any other method to get correlation? or help me to calculate it?

Comment: You seem to have made some mistakes because $\text{Cov}(X, Y)$ is just a number.  It can't be a function of unspecified constants $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Also, your joint pdf is only a function of $y$. Are you missing an $x$ somewhere in there?

Comment: @measure_theory: the density depends on $x$ through the indicator function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you should apply the rules of conditional expectation and variance:

$E(Y) = E(E(Y|X))$ and $\mbox{var}(Y) = \mbox{var}(E(Y|X))+ E(\mbox{var}(Y|X))$.

The conditional distribution of $X$ is a pretty easy one. The marginal distribution of $Y$ is as well, but you must state what they are.